# Как заменить идентификатор пользователя в модуле "Социальная сеть" Битрикса на другое значение?

Tags: php, .htaccess, битрикс, чпу

В настройках модуля "Социальная сеть" Битрикса прописан такой путь
Профайл пользователя:user/#user_id#/

Компонент меняет #user_id# на идентификатор пользователя и получается например такой адрес site.ru/user/33/

Можно ли как-то поменять адрес, что бы ЧПУ был таким site.ru/user/NameLastname/
? 
NameLastname - это имя и фамилия пользователя

Comment: а в настройках компонента есть настройка ЧПУ или ссылок?

Answer (score 1):

При использовании комплексного компонента "Социальная сеть". В визуальном редакторе компонент расположен по пути Общение > Социальная сеть > Социальная сеть. Есть возможность настроить ЧПУ так как вам нужно и соответственно заменить id на имя и фамилию или другой параметр. Вот [ссылка](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/obschenie/social_network/socnet.php) на документацию с описанием параметров компонента.

Если на странице используется не комплексный компонент Социальная сеть, а компонент Социальная сеть - пользователь (комплексный компонент). В визуальном редакторе компонент расположен по пути Общение > Социальная сеть > Социальная сеть - пользователь. То у него есть такие же настройки. Вот [документация](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/obschenie/social_network/socnet_user.php) по параметрам.